# how to get the object from its attribute in python?

Tags: python

I want to do something like this:

```
class B():
    def __init__(self,c):
        self.c=c
    def getA(self):
        #this is what I want
class A():
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.b = B(d)

a = A(d)
```

what I want is that when I perform

```
a.b.getA()
```

I can get the object a that use this method by its attribute b.
I can't pass any new variable to the function because this in implementation is a class written by other people that changing the input variables means changing a lot of stuff.

Can anyone help?

Comment: but you already have `a`, don't you?

Comment: seems that way to me... `a.b.getA()`

Comment: @sobolevn I can only modify the method getA(), so I want to get the object using this method.

Comment: No, you can't do that. References have only one direction. Objects never know what other objects (note: plural!) may reference them. The exception is when you explicitly store a reference in the object (eg modifying class B so it stores a reference to A, which must then be initialized)

Comment: I am not the one using the object a. In other word, I need a function in b that can get the object a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that you construct the `B` instance within the `A` constructor, then give your `B` instance a reference to the `A` instance:

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, c, a):
        self.c = c
        self.a = a
    def getA(self):
        return self.a

class A():
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.b = B(d, self)

a = A(d)
```

---

It is possible under **certain** Python implementations to sometimes find an instance using the [`gc.get_referrers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers), but as the documentation says, using it should be avoided *"for any purpose other than debugging."*:

```
import gc

class B():
    def __init__(self,c):
        self.c = c

    def getA(self):
        for i in gc.get_referrers(self):
            if not isinstance(i, dict):
                continue

            for j in gc.get_referrers(i):
                if isinstance(j, A) and getattr(j, 'b', None) is self:
                    return j

        return

class A():
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.b = B(d)

a = A(42)
print(a.b.getA() is a)
```

The first `get_referrers` call will find among others, the `__dict__` of the `A` instance; this would probably be of type `dict`; we then go through all the objects of the dictionaries referring to `self`, and if any of these is of type `A`, and it has attribute `b` whose value `is self`, we return that object.

Thus the clause `print(a.b.getA() is a)` shall print true.

But seriously, don't use this code.

Comment: Is there a way I don't need to change the initial method of the classes, I'm trying to keep modifications in a single method to minimize the modification of the code. Changing initialization will change a lot of things.